# Having trouble with JQuery .closest & .remove

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a button that contains the `.closest & .remove` into an `.append` but only the existing button works.  I want to be able to click the "New Line" button and have a new line .append and then also be able to "Remove" any of the lines that get added but only the one in that line.

The button

```
<button id="addLine">New Line</button>
```

when clicked adds a new table to the

```
<div id="orderForm">
```

This is what is added

```
$('#orderForm').append('<table class="orderLine" width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td><input name="field1" type="text" id="field1" size="25" tabindex="1"></td><td><button id="removeLine">remove()</button></td></tr></table>');
```

Thats fine and working. I've also added

```
$("#removeLine").click(function () {
 $('#removeLine').closest('.orderLine').remove();
});
```

BUT it only works on the first line that was existing.

Here is the full code.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include '../_includes/jq.inc.php';?><br>
</head>
<body>

<button id="removeAll">Delete All</button>
<button id="addLine">New Line</button>

<div id="orderForm">
<table class="orderLine" width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="field1" type="text" id="field1" size="25" tabindex="1"></td>
        <td><button id="removeLine">remove()</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#removeLine").click(function () {
 $('#removeLine').closest('.orderLine').remove();
});

<!-- This removes all newLine table rows -->
     $("#removeAll").click(function () {
      $('.orderLine').remove();
    });

<!-- ADDS the 'newLine' table rows -->
    $("#addLine").click(function () {

    $('#orderForm').append('<table class="orderLine" width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td><input name="field1" type="text" id="field1" size="25" tabindex="1"></td><td><button id="removeLine">remove()</button></td></tr></table>');
    });

</script>
</html>
```

I've checked it over and checked it over and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No two elements can have the same `id` - use classes and [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

HTML:

```
<button class="removeLine">remove()</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#orderForm").delegate(".removeLine", "click", function () {
    $(this).closest('.orderLine').remove();
});
```

Delegation lets you listen to events triggered by elements that have not yet been added to the document.  In this case, it attaches a handler to `orderForm` that listens to click events triggered on `.removeLine` elements that either currently exist or will be added in the future.

Comment: That's great. It works now. I'll read up on event delegation thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to attache event handlers to elements that are not present in the DOM at the time the events are bound.

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at the [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in stead of the [jQuery.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/). jQuery.click will only bind once (in your case only the initial remove buttons), while jQuery.live will also bind new elements which match the selector. Also i think it's better to use a class for your remove button, because you have more then one remove button so an id isn't valid html. You can only have one DOM element with the same ID. But you can have more DOM elements with the same class.

```
$('.removeButton').live('click' function() {
  $(this).closest('.orderLine').remove();
});
```